# Tag badge achievement caused strange rendering

Tags: bug, design, mobile-web

On mobile, after you dismiss the notification of a tag badge you were tracking, a strange layout appears.

> [image: Screenshot]

I guess there are some broken HTML element or CSS rendering problems causing this.

Can this be fixed please?

Comment: Repro'd on desktop Chrome... the AJAX loads the full site HTML structure instead of the mobile version